# Search JSON values in array using underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have the file `default.json`:

```
{
    "IPs": {
        "ip1": "192.168.0.1",
        "ip2": "192.168.0.2",
        "ip3": "192.168.0.3"
    }
}
```

My code:

```
var _      = require('underscore'),
    config = require('default.json')

var array  = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2']

//search array in IPs
```

How can I search values of `array` in `IPs` (`ip1`, `ip2`, `ip3`) and whenever it's true, call a function? Preferably using an underscore function.

Comment: Do you mean `"ip1": "192.168.0.1"` instead of `"ip1: 192.168.0.1"`? (note the quotes).

Comment: You should also use a comma `,` after each line of the JSON file.

Comment: default.json is invalid JSON.  You're defining an object using {} but you're not using keys and values, unless you remove the quotation marks around the whole line and just place them on the ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks, I've already edited.

Comment: Your `default.json` is still invalid unless you remove the `"IPs":` part, **or** add surrounding `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution (with `underscore`):

File `default.json`

```
    {
        "IPs": {
            "ip1": "192.168.0.1",
            "ip2": "192.168.0.2",
            "ip3": "192.168.0.3"
        }
    }
```

The code:

```
var _      = require('underscore'),
    config = require('default.json')

var array = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2']
var IPs   = config.IPs

_.each(IPs, function(e, k){
    //if find IPs in array
    if(array.indexOf(e) > -1)
        //do something
    else
        //do something
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fix default.json to be like this:

```
"IPs": {
    ip1: "192.168.0.1",
    ip2: "192.168.0.2",
    ip3: "192.168.0.3"
}
```

You can then search for the IPs matching

```
var foundIPs = Object.keys(config.IPs).filter(function(name) {
  // name will be something like 'ip1', 'ip2', or 'ip3'
  var currIP = config.IPs[name]; // eg. currIP = "192.168.0.1"
  var inArray = array.indexOf(currIP) > -1;
  return inArray;
});
var foundIP = foundIPs.length > 0;
```